# Correct way of using a constant pointer in QT signals

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I want to connect signals and slots and pass a constant pointer as an argument, like so:

ClassA.hpp

```
using another_type_id_t = std::string; 
using type_ids_t = std::set<abc::another_type_id_t>;

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(type_ids_t *);

signals:
FuncA(results::type_ids_t const *a);
```

ClassB.hpp

```
slots:
FuncA(results::type_ids_t const *a)
```

ClassB.cpp

```
qRegisterMetaType<results::type_ids_t *>("results::type_ids_t *");
connect(classAInstance, SIGNAL(FuncA(results::type_ids_t *)),
    this, SLOT(FuncA(results::type_ids_t *));
```

The connect function fails. I cannot use the more modern style of connect because the two classes are not being compiled together. They are aware of each other at runtime. Other connections between them work, but not this one for whatever reason.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please show the exact error message verbatim along with a more complete code sample.  Also, I don't really understand the comment `"I cannot use the more modern style of connect because the two classes are not being compiled together"`.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Also, why do you connect as if you had `FuncA(results::type_ids_t *)`, while expecting to call `FuncA(results::type_ids_t const *)`? You don't even have a function with the former signature — neither in the signal, nor in the slot.